# how to scroll the custom drop down element on fixed height?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am implementing the custom drop down.So I found  a good solution .But There is problem in that the Button Take whole if I want take small button (it is not taking width in css).
Secondly I want  to take drop down should scroll a fixed height ? 
I create two drop down in first I take too much element .In second I take only few element , I want to scroll first drop down on same height as in second .

here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/gMLDb/2/

```
function showOptions(target){
    selectedButton = $(target);
   console.log("target"+target);
   console.log("selectedButton"+selectedButton)

    $("#optionsDisplayDiv").html("");
    var array = this[$(target).attr("data-array")];
    for(var i=0; i< array.length; i++){
        $("#optionsDisplayDiv").append("<div class='optionItem'>" + array[i] + "</div>");
    }
    $("#optionsDisplayDiv").css("width", $(target).width());
    $("#optionsDisplayDiv").css("top", ($(target).position().top + $(target).height()));
    $("#optionsDisplayDiv").show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a id="vehicleType" class="myOptionButton" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" data-corners="false" data-array="vehicleTypeOptions" onclick="showOptions(this)" style="width:200px">Type</a>
<a id="colorType" class="myOptionButton" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" data-corners="false" data-array="vehicleColorOptions" onclick="showOptions(this)" style="width:200px">Color</a>

<div id="optionsDisplayDiv" style="max-height: 100px; height: 100px; overflow: auto;" >
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/emdhie/gMLDb/9/

Answer (score 0):

Giving width of button in css works. Check if your other css in page is overriding your button css.

To have fix height for dropdown you can give `max-height` property in css.

Check fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gMLDb/3/)

### Addon for script

Your js script is traversing same element a lot of time which can give a performance impact.
You can use chaining and caching concept to make your code better.
 Plus follow thumb rule "Never do dom manipulation inside loop".

```
function showOptions(target){
    selectedButton = $(target)     //caching

    var array = this[selectedButton.attr("data-array")],
        option="";
    for(var i=0; i< array.length; i++){
        option += "<div class='optionItem'>" + array[i] + "</div>";
    }
    $("#optionsDisplayDiv").html(option ).css({
                  "width": selectedButton .width(),
                  "top": selectedButton.position().top + selectedButton.height()
     }).show();    //chaining of methods
}
```